# Limitations of K-NN operator

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor

Can the K-NN operator <-> be used to find nearest neighbors when comparing ANY geometry type (point, linestring, polygon etc.) with ANY other geometry type, or are there any limitations? It seems incredible if there are no limitations in this regard!

Comment: The operator itself is not much more than a wrapper for the core functionality of e.g. `ST_Distance`.The KNN ability is a GIST index implementation detail which the operator specifically hooks into when used in the `ORDER BY`, and is purely bbox based - only after determining the bbox neighborhood the true distance between geometries are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains that the operator will calculate distances between any geometry types. Depending on the version of software you are running, the distance calculation might differ (distance between bounding box centroids for polygons, for example, with older versions).

In terms of performance, there are limitations you will want to consider to ensure that indexing is used: use the operator in an ORDER BY clause with one of the arguments essentially a constant for the duration of the query.

See [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/geometry_distance_knn.html)